# Create a grid filled with lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a grid. And I want to fill one cell with some lines like the picture.
What I have:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Here are my code so far:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\draw[step=2cm,very thick] (0,0) grid (4,4);

\draw[red, very thick] (0,2.3) rectangle (1.5,4);



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image: patterned fill]

The `patterns` library provides a number of such patterns.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (4,4);
  \draw[step=2cm,very thick] (0,0) grid (4,4);
  \draw[red, very thick, pattern=north east lines] (0,2.3) rectangle (1.5,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```